# jQuery adding class to id-1, -2, -3 depending on next or previous actions

Tags: jquery

I may be doing things the absolute hard way.

So what I am trying to achieve is 'next' and 'previous' buttons should add class 'active' to a certain string of IDs which go up in numbers.

For example

```
<a class="control-next">Next</a>

<h3 id="project-title-1" class="active">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-2" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-3" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-4" class="">Title</h3>
```

So when you click on control-next it should make project-title-2 active, and so on, so on, control-previous should do the minus.

Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated! All I could figure out is the most basic way ever but it isn't a smart way to progress.

```
$('.control-next').click(function () {
        $('#project-title-1').removeClass('active');
        $('#project-title-2').addClass('active');
});
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work

```js
$('.control-next').on('click', function() {
    var index = $('h3.active').index('h3');
    var active = $('h3.active');
    if (index < $('h3').length - 1) {
        active.next('h3').addClass('active');
        active.removeClass('active');
    }
});

$('.control-prev').on('click', function() {
    var index = $('h3.active').index('h3');
    var active = $('h3.active');
    if (index > 0) {
        active.prev('h3').addClass('active');
        active.removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active { background: gold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="control-next">Next</a>
<a class="control-prev">Previous</a>

<h3 id="project-title-1" class="active">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-2" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-3" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-4" class="">Title</h3>
```

Breakdown

We set a variable for the current `h3` element that has an active class. We search to see if it is the last such element. If so, we will cycle back to the first element. Otherwise, we add the active class to it's subsequent sibling.

Comment: Hit next four times. Then hit previous as many times as you like.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't accounting for the index

Comment: Thank you for a very informative answer! Would it be too complicated to add an indexing system so it would return to 1 again? Do you need to indicate a capped number?

Comment: Indeed, I added an indexing system

Answer (score 0):

Instead of target by id, you could either target by tag name (`h3` in this case), or add an additional class that you add to each heading (if you dont want it to cycle through other h3). Something like this would do it:

```
$('.control-next').click(function(evt) {
    $('.active')
    .removeClass('active')
    .next('h3')
    .addClass('active');
});
```

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovvtct7c/

Comment: The problem with this is it doesn't cycle back to the first one.

Comment: True, I just didn't want to make any assumptions about what he was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```js
$('.control-next').click(function() {
    var idx = $('h3.active').index('h3');
    if (idx + 1 < $('h3').length) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('h3').eq(idx + 1).addClass('active');
    }
});
$('.control-prev').click(function() {
    var idx = $('h3.active').index('h3');
    if (idx > 0) {
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $('h3').eq(idx - 1).addClass('active')
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
    color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="control-next">Next</a>

<h3 id="project-title-1" class="active">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-2" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-3" class="">Title</h3>
<h3 id="project-title-4" class="">Title</h3>

<a class="control-prev">Prev</a>
```

This uses the index of the active element and will stop from going outside the bounds of your headings.

Note that depending on your exact HTML you could streamline this a little more.